# If I don't get a postdoc, how do I know what I did wrong?

Tags: postdocs, early-career

For example, did I make the research statement too technical, etc.?

Also, is it true that a lot of applications don't even get looked at?

Comment: My guess? Your application was too short and lacked detail.

Comment: You are assuming you did something wrong, which is not necessarily the case, there are not enough postdoctoral positions for every PhD graduate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the main reasons postdoc applicants get rejected?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123557/what-are-the-main-reasons-postdoc-applicants-get-rejected)

Comment: Nobody wants to hire me @Dr.Snoopy. I want to know why.

Comment: The search committee isn't going to give you any detailed feedback. If you worry about your research statement being too technical, you need to show it to a trusted senior colleague and ask for feedback.

Comment: If a position is advertised, then applicants will be looked at, until a suitable candidate is found. The final sentence in the comment of @AdamPřenosil is the proper way to proceed.

Comment: Your other questions indicate you are in math.    If you look at recent survey data from the AMS, you will see that only about 50% of new PhDs get an academic position (about 10% are unemployed; some but not all of the remaining 40% wanted an academic position but didn't find one).  Of those getting an academic position, some of the other data suggest about 50% are postdocs, 20% are (almost always teaching-oriented) tenure-track positions, and 30% are teaching-oriented non-tenure track (temporary or permanent) positions.  Moral: what Dr.Snoopy said.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: yeah... but I was wondering how I can know how my application was perceived by the hiring committees.

Comment: If it's something you could've done, then most likely someone will get a word in with your advisor at some point.  Most of the time it's completely out of your control.

Answer (score 1):

Postdocs are expensive. Most people don't have enough spare money laying around to hire one, even if an amazing postdoc candidate comes to their desk.

The other issue is integrating postdocs with a new research group. PIs don't want to just hire a bunch of independent people, they should have a clear vision for how their *team* works together. In other words, there are a lot of factors outside of your control (what type of person/expertise is each PI needing right now? It might not match your background. Or in other words, it's not that you were necessarily bad, you just weren't the right researcher for the job).

Comment: While postdocs are more expensive than a graduate student, they are less expensive than a professor or staff member. But there are fewer postdoc positions than graduate student positions.

Comment: In math most postdocs are not funded by grants.

Comment: True @Moishe I'm speaking from my experience, which is in engineering in the US

Comment: Yes, engineering is quite different, but OP appears to be in math.

Comment: "Postdocs are expensive" This depends on the situation. Compared to a graduate student on a RAship, they're often equal: the rise in salary is about the same as the cost of graduate student tuition and fees. In some private schools with high fees and fields where postdoctoral pay is low, you actually _save_ money. The postdoc tends to be more productive, without a lengthy class/exam period, so the work per dollar is better. Finally, there is funding specifically for postdocs, so it doesn't come out of the same pot of money.